# In WPF application, how can I make events only respond to user operation?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

Below is my code.

*MainWindows.xaml*:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel Margin="5">
        <TextBox x:Name="a" TextChanged="a_TextChanged" />
        <TextBox x:Name="b" Margin="0 5 0 0" TextChanged="b_TextChanged" />
        <TextBox x:Name="c" Margin="0 5 0 0" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

*MainWindow.xaml.cs*:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void a_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            b.Text = "bb";
        }

        private void b_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            c.Text = "cc";
        }
    }
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, when I manually change the text in `a`, `b` was changed programmatically, which in turn changed `c`. I hope `b`'s event handler `b_TextChanged` will only be triggered by user operation (user type some characters in `b`). Programmatically change `b`'s `Text` property should not trigger `b_TextChanged`. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps it is time to switch to MVVM?

```
private string _a;
public string A
{
    get { return _a; }
    set { SetA(value, true); }
}

protected void SetA(string value, bool isUserInput)
{
    _a = value;
    if (isUserInput)
    {
        // aditional operations
    }
    OnPropertyChanged("A");
}
```

User input in TextBox will trigger property setter via binding, `isUserInput` will be `true`.

```
<TextBox x:Name="a" Text="{Binding A}" />
```

Any change from program logic can be done using Set method with `false` flag: `SetA("new value", false);`

Comment: It's almost always a good time to change to mvvm. You might also find you need an isloading flag or some such in your viewmodel for anotyher reason but at least your logic will be discrete and testable.

Comment: @ASh Thanks for your suggestion. Do you have any recommended MVVM framework?

Comment: @Justalearner, the simpler framework - the better. https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmFoundation.Wpf/ is my choice for small projects. Basic implemenatation of INotifyPropertyChanged and ICommand are enough for quick start, IMO

Comment: Such a way you have to create a dedicated method for each property?

Comment: @Rekshino, depend if `additional operations` vary for different properties. Otherwise ref parameter can come to rescue: `SetPropery<T>(ref T field, T value, bool flag)`

Answer (score 1):

Simple use flags to declare, that code behind change is running:

```
namespace WpfApp2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private bool _nonUserChange = false;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void a_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DoNonUserChange(() => b.Text = "bb");
        }

        private void b_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DoNonUserChange(() => c.Text = "cc");
        }

        private void DoNonUserChange(Action act)
        {
            if (act != null && !_nonUserChange)
            {
                _nonUserChange = true;
                act();
                _nonUserChange = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```